# ActiveRecord: efficiently calculating sums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to display analytics for campaigns. Here is some context:

- Campaign statistics are collected by different Companies for specific Ads
- oftentimes, statistics are generated for the same Ad by more than one Company
- statistics are collected in a model called DailyStat
- each campaign involves a number of companies that may or may not be collecting statistics
- campaigns and companies are associated through campaignizations

Campaign -> Ads - > DailyStat

DailyStats belong to both an ad and a company, depending on which company generate the statistics.

The models look as follows:

```
class DailyStat < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ad, :clicks, :company, :date, :impressions

  belongs_to :ad
  belongs_to :company
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :campaign
  has_many :daily_stats
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaignizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :companies, :through => :campaignizations

  has_many :ads, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :campaignizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :campaigns, :through => :campaignizations

end
```

Now, what I want to do most efficiently is:

- retrieve a summary of impressions for a specific campaign (by company)
- retrieve a summary of impressions for each ads for a specifc campaign (by company)

Being fairly new to ActiveRecord, I have tried playing around with includes, sums etc., but can't seem to wrap my head around how to get from campaign to company-grouped stats (short of iterating over all ads).

Questions I have:

1. What would be an efficient approach to tackle this?
2. Would it make sense to denormalize and add campaign information to DailyStats?

Comment: In my experience, when you start to build aggregates, ActiveRecord also starts to show its limits : the only aggregates you can make are very basic and clumsy (for example, #sum lets you only sum a single column, that's it... no window functions, and no grouping, at least not easily ). You should use raw SQL (or Arel if you manage to make it through the lack of good docs) + the "low-level" facilities like [select_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all). AR was designed towards CRUD activities, not data-crunching...

Comment: Another option is to have a job crunch the numbers for you every day, and save the results in an additional table... If you find more convenient ways to do this kind of job, please let us know ! On the other hand, if you do not have any sums / calculations to perform, you can easily find the required records with AR query api.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You are probably right. I have since tried the same thing in SQL. Took about 5 minutes :D

I'll leave this question open for now, maybe there is a great tool that we both don't know about :)

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to achieve complex aggregate calculations with arel / AR, though somewhat complex... here's an example (not sure if it works, but you get the spirit) :

retrieve a summary of impressions for a specific campaign (by company) :

```
DailyStat
  .joins(  company: {campaignizations: :campaign} )
  .where(  Campaign.arel_table[:id].eq arbitrary_id )
  .group(  DailyStat.arel_table[:company_id] )
  .select([ 
             DailyStat.arel_table[:impressions].sum, 
             DailyStat.arel_table[:company_id] 
          ])
```

as i said, i don't know if this works - you can run into a LOT of unexpected problems when using groups + select AND object instanciation (don't forget that AR instantiates a `DailyStat` object for each row returned, whatever it makes sense or not), so you better stick to raw SQL / pure Arel with `select_all`.

Another option to consider, if your RDBMS allows it, is to use a DB View. With a bit of hacking, it is possible to use a AR model to access a DB view as if it was a table... which can be tremendously helpful.